# softkeyboard in landscape mode does not pop up in android emulator

Tags: android

In android emulator, I am in landscape mode and double click the text edit panel. the softkeyboard does not show up. However, it works in portrait mode.

I have check some of posts on line. They said because of hardkeyboard is available in landscape mode. If that so, how can i disable the hardkeyboard. Or is there any setting reason for this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default emulator has a hard keyboard. When you put it in landscape mode it doesn't show the softkeyboard.

To solve this, create a new `AVD` and in Hardware properties add:

```
Keyboard support "no"
```

Comment: For some reason creating the AVD through the UI didn't work. I had to edit the config.ini file and put: `hw.keyboard=no`

Comment: @Cristian: mmmm I am sure it worked in the past, perhaps it doesn't with the new SDK.